# Passing Large Html Content to API Controller in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, api

I have created an api controller which is supposed to receive some html content. When the call fires, chrome shows the status of `PUT` request as pending for a looong long time.

Initially i thought the problem is with the html tags but once i tried small tags i discovered it worked.

Now i am guessing the problem is with the size of content which is the content of a full html page.

here is the code:

```
            <script>
            $("#createHtmlElement").click(function (event) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/api/PageElements/@Model.Id",
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    type: "PUT",
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        Content: $("#newHtmlContent").val()
                    }),
                    success: function (html) {
                    }
                });

            });

        </script>
```

here is the c# code for the API:

```
public class PageElementsController : ApiController
{
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public void Put(int id, HtmlElement value)
    {
        HtmlContent contents = new HtmlContent(value.Content);
        this.htmlElementBL.SaveHtmlContentElements(contents, id);
    }

}
```

I need to either change my approach as to how i am passing data or find out what is the problem that it is not working with the large content.

Comment: How large is 'large'?  Is it larger than your setting for `maxRequestLength` in `WEB.CONFIG`.  The default value is only 4096KB.

Comment: not too large. just a html page of a simple website like http://www.simplesite.com/

Comment: simple debugging through, or using a stopwatch or something, where is it taking so much time.  The webpage you linked is only like 40k, that should be quick